# Dovecot: autocreate plugin is deprecated, use mailbox { auto } setting

Tags: configuration, email-server, dovecot

Currently I am using this in my dovecot.conf:

```
protocol imap {
mail_plugins = "autocreate"
}

plugin {
autocreate = Trash
autocreate2 = Sent
autosubscribe = Trash
autosubscribe2 = Sent
}
```

My log says: Warning: autocreate plugin is deprecated, use mailbox { auto } setting

I checked [this page](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings), but I am not able to "translate" my current settings into what it should be.

Answer (score 6):

I just started experimenting with this myself, but I believe that in your case you need to replace these lines:

```
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = "autocreate"
}

plugin {
  autocreate = Trash
  autocreate2 = Sent
  autosubscribe = Trash
  autosubscribe2 = Sent
}
```

With:

```
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes

  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe # autocreate and autosubscribe the Trash mailbox
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe # autocreate and autosubscribe the Sent mailbox
    special_use = \Sent
  }
}
```

And finally `service dovecot restart`.

Comment: In my case (I'm using Vesta 0.9.8-19), the only thing missing was the part where the autocreate plugin is added to the config. Restarting dovecot then created the folders just fine, and no warning was written to the log.

Comment: namespace doc - https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/namespace/